# Machine learning with categorical data: Can I delete examples?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a machine learning project that uses a bunch of features to predict a class that has categorical values. The possible values are:

1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

I'm interested whether the class has the value 1 or not. Therefore I added a new binary variable that is 1 when the class is 1 and 0 otherwise. So far so good. The problem now is that my data set is quite small ~200 observations and the features for the values the class has are very close to each other. That is, it is very hard to distinguish between 1 and 2, but it would be way easier to distinguish for example between 1 and 5.

Is there anything I can do do improve my results? For example, I'm really not interested whether when the instance I'm going to predict has the value 3. I just want a classifier that is good in recognizing 1 events.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in distinguishing between the 1 and non-1 outputs, the standard method is indeed to build a binary classifier (e.g. a SVM or a Maxent model) that will attempt to divide the two classes based on the provided features.  You do not need to delete examples (it's nearly always a bad idea to remove data, epecially when the data set is small).  It's better to replace the values 2,...5 but a "not-1" value to simplity the problem to one of binary classification. You might want to use non-linear SVMs if the boundary between the two classes is particularly complex.

If the numbers 1,2,...5 reflect some ordinal variable (i.e. if you are not really interested in the numbers per se, but rather in the relative ordering between data points), it might be worth looking at methods for "ordinal regression" instead of classification.